# How can I avoid circular dependency when exporting from main file to utils and back in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor that I initialize in my main Javascript file that we will call `main.js` and then I have a separate file called: `utils.js`, in utils I will just print the name in a function and export back the function to the main file but it gives me circular dependency warning and returns undefined:

```js
const { test } = require("./utils");

class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

const user = new User({
  name: "Oscar",
});

console.log("Your name is: %s!", user.name); // Outputs: { name: 'Oscar' }

test() // This gives me undefined and also circular dependency warning

module.exports = {
  user,
};
```

And then in the utils file I want to simply do:

```js
const { user } = require("./main");

const test = () => {
  console.log("Hello there %s!", user.name);
};

module.exports = {
  test,
}
```

How can I export back `test` function to `main` and avoid having circular dependency issues?

Comment: Somewhat tangential, but why do this in a way that’s circular? There’s rarely a good reason.

Comment: You can move `user` to a separate file and import this file from both other files. Or you can pass `user` as a parameter to `test()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, frist file has tree responsibilities:

1. Defining user class
2. Initializing user class
3. Making something with user

So, good practice is to separate them.
main.js

```
const { test } = require("./utils");
const { user } = require("./create-user");

console.log("Your name is: %s!", user.name); // Outputs: { name: 'Oscar' }

test() // This gives me undefined and also circular dependency warning

module.exports = {
  user,
};
```

create-user.js

```
const { User } = require("./user");

const user = new User({
  name: "Oscar",
});

module.exports = {
  user,
};
```

user.js

```
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}


module.exports = {
  User,
};
```

utils.js

```
const { user } = require("./create-user");

const test = () => {
  console.log("Hello there %s!", user.name);
};

module.exports = {
  test,
}
```